# Office.js Get calendar resource id

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have a Task Pane in `Appointment Compose` window

We want to detect whether meeting/appointment is being created in user's calendar or group calendar

`Office.context.mailbox` does not have any properties related to calendar and same with `Office.context.mailbox.item`

`Office.context.mailbox.userProfile` contains logged in user details only

Any way to get calender id using `Office.js`

Edit: also `group id` will suffice our need

Comment: While there are calendar specific properites on Office.context.mailbox.item such as requiredAttendees (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.5), there's no property to check whether the meeting / appointment is created in user's or group's calendar. I notice you also ask about getting the id, how do you plan to use it for the detection?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Actually we need graph api reference to `Event`. It is trivial for user as we get event Id using `saveAsync`, and using `me` domain in graph calls, But we dont know how to do fo group calender

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to get that information via the Office.js. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user voice page. Please add your request here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins.

Comment: MSFT team, is this still relevant? We would really like to not resort to hacky methods of testing if certain calendar properties are present to detect we are in calendar mode and not in regular mail mode.

Comment: how did you solve this problem, could you kindly share?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT is this solved? How can we have the same ID for Organizer and Attendee?